# VSCode PHP Debug - exception on undefined variable

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I'm using a current version (v1.13.0) of the PHP Debug extension with XDebug in PHP 7.4. All seems fine in that I can hit breakpoints etc. but the IDE breaks on any line that has an undefined variable:

```
Exception has occurred.
Notice: Undefined variable: myVar
```

I don't believe this to be a code issue and php itself does not give any complaints with all E_ALL logging, is there any way to make the debugger ignore such errors?

Answer (score 0):

This problem is resolved but I'm not sure what sorted it out, after restarting IIS and VSCode I no longer see this behaviour so perhaps one of those actions did the trick.